# Found nil when i tried to do some function after dismissViewController by swift.

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I need to refresh my carousel slider on the background view after dismissViewController from the modal view.

This my code.

On app delegate.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var customDisplayViewController: customInsideViewController?
    // this is background view
```

On background view.

```
func refreshCarousel(){
    self.carousel.reloadData()
}
```

On modal view

```
@IBAction func closeModal(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
        let appdelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        appdelegate.customDisplayViewController!.refreshCarousel()
        //fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    })
}
```

But i got 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
After dismissView was completed.

So anyone know how to fix this.
Thanks!

Comment: Replace `!` with `?` (`appdelegate.customDisplayViewController!...`) and read [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).

Comment: Also assure yourself that `customDisplayViewController` property on `AppDelegate` is set. It's not set, that's the reason why `!` crashes your app.

Comment: When i change to this

appdelegate.customDisplayViewController?.refreshCarousel()

The App didn't crashes but didn't run this function refreshCarousel() also.
What should i do?

Comment: See my 2nd comment, your customDisplayViewController is nil -> nothing happens. Be sure it's set.

Comment: Hmm i already assigned customDisplayViewController to one of my view in my storyboard. But still doesn't work.

Comment: How? Your customDisplayViewController is not @IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0):

@robertvojta

I mean i already have this.

[image]

Comment: Do use camel case for types with upper cased first character. Class should be `CustomInsideViewController` (upper case `C`). Convention is `MyTypeStructClassEnumOrWhatever` as a type and `customInsideViewController` as a property. So you can easily distinguish between them.

Comment: _Storyboard ID_ is used to identify your view controller when you do want to instantiate it programmatically for example. (`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String) -> UIViewController` on `UIStoryboard`).

Comment: _Custom Class - Class_ & `customInsideViewController` just says that the view controller is of class `customInsideViewController` and not the default one (`UIViewController`).

Comment: You have to mark `var customDisplayViewController: customInsideViewController?` with `@IBOutlet` and connect your view controller with this property in Storyboard. It's not connected. So far you have view controller identifier, custom view controller class, but it's not connected with your property.

Comment: So now i already have this
@IBOutlet var customDisplayViewController: customInsideViewController? on my appDelegate.
But how can i connect my view controller in Storyboard with this?